# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process --- EF Core serializing XML

Tags: filestream, xmlserializer

I am trying to write a method to fetch the categories and their respective products from the Northwind database and to then use xml serialization to write to a file.

I have tried the following code but get the error detailed in the heading. (The file is created but no XML is written to it).

Is anyone able to advise what is wrong with my code ?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
static async void SerializeCategoriesWithXML() {
    FileStream xmlFileStream = null;
    XmlWriter xml = null;

    // Create file to write to :
    string path = Combine(CurrentDirectory, "CategoriesAndTheirProducts.xml");
    // Create a file stream :
    xmlFileStream = File.Create(path);

    // Wrap the file stream in an Xml writer helper and automatically indent the nested elements :
    xml = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFileStream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true });

    using (var db = new NorthwindContext())
    {

        // A query to get all categories and their related products :   
        IQueryable<Categories> cats = db.Categories
            .Include(c => c.Products
            .ToList());

        await using (FileStream stream = File.Create(path))
        {
            // Write the Xml declaration :
            xml.WriteStartDocument();

            // Serialize the object graph to the stream :
            foreach (Categories c in cats)
            {
                // Write a root element :
                xml.WriteStartElement("category");
                foreach(Products p in c.Products)
                {
                    xml.WriteElementString("product", p.ProductName);
                }
                // Write the closing root element :
                xml.WriteEndElement();
                xml.Flush();                        
            }

            // CLose the helper and stream :
            xml.Close();
            xmlFileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify the language you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the code being shared.

Lets try to understand each problem and think of a possible solution to the problem - 
The problem statement as far as I understand is, you wanted to create a XML file with category and products under the category. So for simplicity I assume you are trying to get a XML file as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<categories>
  <category>
    <product>Chai</product>
    <product>Chang</product>
    <product>Guaraná Fantástica</product>
    <product>Sasquatch Ale</product>
    <product>Steeleye Stout</product>
    <product>Côte de Blaye</product>
  </category>
  <category>
    <product>Aniseed Syrup</product>
    <product>Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning</product>
    <product>Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix</product>
    <product>Grandma's Boysenberry Spread</product>
  </category>
</categories>
```

Coming to what's wrong with above posted code -
Problem 1: Multiple Creation of file with the specified path -

```
// Create a file stream :
xmlFileStream = File.Create(path);
```

you have already fired File.Create in the above line so when you are firing the below code it is saying **file already in use**.... (the below line is not required)

```
await using (FileStream stream = File.Create(path))
```

Problem 2: Linq query is not right. You can replace your linq query with the below code -

```
var cats = db.Categories
      .Include(c => c.Products).ToList();
```

Problem 3: Xml construction is wrong...
You need to wrap the category tag inside a parent as multiple category objects will get created. Also in the code above you are trying to flush the xml when one category is read. You need to perform flush once the last

```
xml.WriteEndElement();
```

is executed.

So you can replace the code block for creating xml as below -

```
            // Write the Xml declaration :
            xml.WriteStartDocument();
            xml.WriteStartElement("categories");

            // Serialize the object graph to the stream :
            foreach (Categories c in cats)
            {
                // Write a root element :
                xml.WriteStartElement("category");
                foreach (Products p in c.Products)
                {
                    xml.WriteElementString("product", p.ProductName);
                }

                // Write the closing root element :
                xml.WriteEndElement();                    
            }

            xml.WriteEndElement();
            xml.Flush();

            // CLose the helper and stream :
            xml.Close();
            xmlFileStream.Close();
```

Now the file should get created with the categories->category[].
And each category->product[].

Thanks

Comment: Dear Sir ,Thank you for the extraordinary effort you have made to help.

Comment: Glad if it helped. By the way no need to address as sir. We all are learning. And knowledge sharing helps. Please mark it as answer if that helped.

Comment: Dear Sir ,Thank you for the extraordinary effort you have made to help. Unfortunately, that brings me back to the original problem I had...the error of "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid".  When I remove the "Include", I cannot access the products.

Comment: This problem has been addressed in the above solution, that is Problem 2. If you simply copy paste the above code under problem 2 should fix your issue. Pay attention to brackets in your code.
In your code you have written var cats = db.Categories
      .Include(c => c.Products.ToList()); which is incorrect. You need to write

var cats = db.Categories
      .Include(c => c.Products).ToList();